# ¿ Cómo puedo combinar jQuery Multidatespicker a bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: bootstrap, jquery-ui, jquery-datepicker

Estoy intentando realizar una página en la que hay varias posibilidades de incluir fechas y de ver los desplegables de las mismas.

Hasta ahora estaba utilizando el plugin multidatespicker de jquery-ui para mostrar un calendario completo y seleccionar varias fechas.

Ahora necesito incorporar el plugin datepicker de Bootstrap para poder usar otro tipo de calendario.

El caso es que entran en conflicto y en cuanto incorporo el bootstrap-datepicker.min.js por lo que sea el multidatespicker deja de funcionar (ya no se muestra un calendario completo sino solo un mes, como si fuese un unico mes).

Es posible que al usar los dos la función de datepicker den conflicto, ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?.